# Executing the latest ruleset version deployed on the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When I make changes to the RuleApp or ruleset and deploy it to the Business Rules service on Bluemix, the version is updated.

To invoke the latest ruleset version, I have to update the client app to use the Execution URL (from the Ruleset Details page of the Business Rules service) which uses the new version.

I do not want to keep updating the client app with the new URL to execute the latest ruleset version. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I deployed the RuleApp from the Rule Designer, I found that I could select the deployment type as the "Replace RuleApp version" option.

This did not update the RuleApp or ruleset version, which meant that I did not have to update the URL used by the client application, to be able to execute the latest ruleset version.